# Two finger scroll not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, 15.10

I use Lenovo yoga 500 80N40046IN and i've installed Ubuntu 15.10.Two finger scroll doesn't work.I've tried deselecting two finger scroll and natural scroll in mouse and touchpad settings.Still doesn't wok.I even tried running synclient twofingerscroll=1 through terminal.Yet the same problem.Please help.

Output of xinput command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of xinput list-props 14:

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (298):  1585, 5357, 1417, 4437
    Synaptics Finger (299): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (300):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (301):   247
    Synaptics Tap Durations (302):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (303):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (304):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (305):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (306):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (307): 155, 1232369007
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (308): 1, 1, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (309):   1, 0
    Synaptics Move Speed (310): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.035606, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (311):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (312):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (313):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (314): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (315):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (316): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (317):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (318): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (319):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (320): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (321):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (322): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (323):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (324): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (325):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (326):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (327):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (328):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (329): 52, 42
    Synaptics Area (330):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (331):  3471, 0, 4050, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (332): 8, 8
    Device Product ID (260):    2, 7
    Device Node (261):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

> ## EVEMU 1.2
>
> ## Input device name: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"

## Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x02 product 0x07 version 0x1b1

## Supported events:

## Event type 0 (EV_SYN)

## Event code 0 (SYN_REPORT)

## Event code 1 (SYN_CONFIG)

## Event code 2 (SYN_MT_REPORT)

## Event code 3 (SYN_DROPPED)

## Event code 4 ((null))

## Event code 5 ((null))

## Event code 6 ((null))

## Event code 7 ((null))

## Event code 8 ((null))

## Event code 9 ((null))

## Event code 10 ((null))

## Event code 11 ((null))

## Event code 12 ((null))

## Event code 13 ((null))

## Event code 14 ((null))

## Event type 1 (EV_KEY)

## Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)

## Event code 325 (BTN_TOOL_FINGER)

## Event code 328 (BTN_TOOL_QUINTTAP)

## Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)

## Event code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP)

## Event code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP)

## Event code 335 (BTN_TOOL_QUADTAP)

## Event type 3 (EV_ABS)

## Event code 0 (ABS_X)

## Value   3317

## Min     1278

## Max     5664

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 42

## Event code 1 (ABS_Y)

## Value   3650

## Min     1172

## Max     4682

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 52

## Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)

## Value      0

## Min        0

## Max      255

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 0

## Event code 28 (ABS_TOOL_WIDTH)

## Value      0

## Min        0

## Max       15

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 0

## Event code 47 (ABS_MT_SLOT)

## Value      0

## Min        0

## Max        1

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 0

## Event code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X)

## Value      0

## Min     1278

## Max     5664

## Fuzz       8

## Flat       0

## Resolution 42

## Event code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y)

## Value      0

## Min     1172

## Max     4682

## Fuzz       8

## Flat       0

## Resolution 52

## Event code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID)

## Value      0

## Min        0

## Max    65535

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 0

## Event code 58 (ABS_MT_PRESSURE)

## Value      0

## Min        0

## Max      255

## Fuzz       0

## Flat       0

## Resolution 0

## Properties:

## Property  type 0 (INPUT_PROP_POINTER)

## Property  type 2 (INPUT_PROP_BUTTONPAD)

N: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
I: 0011 0002 0007 01b1
P: 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 20 e5 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 03 03 00 00 11 00 80 60 06
B: 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
B: 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
A: 00 1278 5664 0 0 42
A: 01 1172 4682 0 0 52
A: 18 0 255 0 0 0
A: 1c 0 15 0 0 0
A: 2f 0 1 0 0 0
A: 35 1278 5664 8 0 42
A: 36 1172 4682 8 0 52
A: 39 0 65535 0 0 0
A: 3a 0 255 0 0 0

#

## Waiting for events

#

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `xinput list-props 14`

Comment: Everything looks OK.

Comment: Yeah!Still doesn't work!Is it like it might work in previous versions of ubuntu like ubuntu 14?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in 15.10. Try 14.04.3 live image.

Comment: Install `evemu-tools`. Then run `sudo evemu-record /dev/input/event4 > evemu.log`, scroll with two fingers, then press Ctrl + C. Then provide that `evemu.log` file.